# Add Category column based on string values in another column where some words overlap - R Studio

Tags: r

I am trying to add a "category" column to my dataframe based on string values from another column containing call center verbiage. The issue is that some of the words overlap.

Here's reproducible example of the data:

df$DESC <-
"the night sky is black", "a black and white zebra", "horrible black and gold", "Halloween black and green", "black and white stripes", "black and green flag"

From this I want to get a category column that would have the following corresponding values: 1,2,3,4,2,4

Here is what I tried:

```
          df$category <- ifelse (df$DESC %in% ("black"), '1',

             ifelse (df$DESC %in% ("black and white"), '2',

              ifelse (df$DESC %in% ("black and gold"), '3',

               ifelse (df$DESC %in% ("black and green"), '4',

                   "" ))))
```

The above code fills in the value 2 but does not capture 1, 3, and 4. I'm assuming it is because of the common word "black" but I don't know how to fix. I also tried grepl and case statements and read through numerous stack overflow posts, but didn't get anywhere. Can someone please advise? Thanks.

Comment: Please share a reproducible piece of your data so that others can use it and help you more efficiently.

Comment: your are trying to do partial matching... the %in% operador is for exact matches where you can supply a list of values (but they have to match completely... much like the IN in SQL). You should use stringr::str_detect(df$DESC, pattern = "black and green")... also I would recomend you to read into "case_when()" (which is multiple ifelse but a bit more concise to read and write)

Comment: @DPH, thanks--I did take this advice and edited my code to use str_detect and case statements. That works well.

Comment: @alminmd please consider to acept or upvote my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers